# What am I doing wrong. (Basic PFD)

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate:
>   $$\int \frac{e^x}{e^{2x} + 3e^x + 2} dx$$

*My solution*: Let $u = e^x$, then $$\int \frac{u}{u^2+3u+2} du=\dots$$

and $\frac{u}{(u+1)(u+2)} = \frac{A}{u+2} + \frac{B}{u+1}$ with $A = 2, B = -1$. So, 
$$\dots=-2 \ln |u + 2| - \ln |u+1| + C$$ resubstitute: $= 2 \ln |e^x + 2| - \ln |e^x+1| + C$. Apparently the answer is this: $$\ln(1 + e^x) - \ln(2 + e^x) + C$$

Comment: $u=e^x$ implies that $du=e^xdx=udx$ so $dx=\frac1udu$

Comment: So basically $\frac{u^2}{u^2+3u+2} du$ will give me the answer?

Comment: nvm, I'm confused

Comment: No, the $u$ get's simplified, not squared. But I think you got it already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT 
              The mistake is here :

[image]

Comment: Oh! Nvm I got it. Hope u didnt see my edit. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

No $u$ in the numerator. You forgot that $du = e^x\,dx$.